# Moving elements in an auto layout instance - Figma

Tags: interface-design, figma, user-experience, components

Hi I'm fairly new to figma. Learning tutorials. Just wondering I've created a component with text and made that into an auto layout so that I am able to switch around text/add if needed. I then made an instance of that component and am trying to switch text around and its not working. For some reason it only works on the master component?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem. You cannot change the structure of the instance itself while using it.

1. For this, you will have to create multiple variants at the master level. Then use the right instance at the right places.
2. Another hacky option is to just edit the field names of 1 and 2 to 2 and 1 to swap them at an instance level. But this is not scalable.